# terminology "possible sequences of a set"

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, order-theory

I am not a mathematician but am wanting to informally research some math topics related to order and combinatorics. Up to now unable to discover the right terms to use in a math context, so that I can research more. Attempts at terminology are ***bold italicized***. **Please correct my terminology errors**.

Members/Elements are represented below with numbers.
Sets and sequences are represented by enclosure in brackets {}.
Partitions/groups are represented below by enclosure in parentheses ().

- A sequence ...

  ***sequenceA*** = {1,2,3}
- An ***inclusion order*** ...

  ***power set of sequenceA*** =

{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}

- And then including the idea of ***partitioning the power set*** ...

  ***partitioned power set of sequenceA*** =

{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}, {(1,2,)3}, {1,(2,3)}

- possibilities for sequence order ...

  ***set of permutations of sequenceA*** =

{1, 2, 3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}

- Then I am wanting to bring in an operation of an inclusion order on the *set of permutations of sequenceA*, so the idea of including increasing quantity of elements, like a power set is built up... and yields possibilities in a case of having both sequential order and inclusion order ... seems like a union of power sets of permutations of sequenceA ...

  ***power set of permutations of sequenceA***  =

{},{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {1,3}, {3,1}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}

- finally I am trying to include partitioning as well as inclusion order and sequential order ...

  ***partitioned power set of permutations of sequenceA*** =

{},{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {1,3}, {3,1}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1}, {3,1,2}, {3,2,1}, {(1,2),3}, {(2,1),3}, {3,(1,2)}, {3,(2,1)}, {1,(2,3)}, {1,(3,2)},{(2,3),1}, {(3,2),1}, {2,(1,3)}, {2,(3,1)}, {(1,3),2}, {(3,1),2}

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

{a,b,c} is a set.  It is never a sequence.
Sequences are ordered n-tuples.
(a,b,c) is a sequence.
(b,c,a) is a different sequence.
{b,c,a} is not a different set.
It is the same as {a,b,c},

There is no such thing as the power set of a sequence.
The power set of the set A = {1,2,3} is
{ {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3} }.
{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}
is not the powerset of A.
It is a list of the elements of the power set of A.